# Issue with drop in angular-dragdrop

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

The drop works very well but when i specify width to the div where I drop the drop is disabled.

I want to know if there is a way to specify width without disabling drop?

```
 <div style="width:100%;">
        <div>
        <div class="inline" class="inline"> {{qpart1}} </div>
            <div class="inline" style='width:50px'>
        <div  style='height:25px;background-color: #007fff' data-drop={{candrop}} multiple='fasle' data-jqyoui-options ng-model="list2" jqyoui-droppable >
            <div class="btn btn-success"  style='width:50px' data-drag="false" data-jqyoui-options ng-model="list2" jqyoui-draggable ng-hide="!list2.title">{{list2.title}}</div>
        </div>
            </div>
        <div  class="inline">  {{qpart2}}</div><br><br><br>
    </div>

    <div ng-repeat="rep in rps">
        <decorate-dargs></decorate-dargs>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please rephrase the question, is hard to understand what the problem is.

Comment: Inspect the dom, when you've changed the width what are the changes on your drop div, what other changes are present on that element, that aren't present without the width change?

Comment: the same dom except  the width